# Adding bash to a yocto image

Tags: bash, yocto

I'm building a `rpi-basic-image` with below `conf/local.conf` changes but the yocto image doesn't include `bash` under `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. How can I include the `bash` to my image?

```
CONF_VERSION = "1"
MACHINE = "raspberrypi3"
PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-raspberrypi = "4.%"
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "x11 wayland"
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " glibc-utils"
IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE = "500000"
```

Comment: `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " bash"` ?

Comment: Thank you @Nayfe.

Comment: we also use IMAGE_INSTALL += "bash"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below command in your `build/conf/local.conf`

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " bash"
```

Comment: we also use IMAGE_INSTALL += "bash"